# Display ID sharing 2 values from same attribute

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the eNum (employee number) of that who masters 2 values (MySQL and Python) from the same attribute column, The closest I get is down below, but the eNum is duplicated. I want to get just one eNum once. I think I am messing it up in the WHERE clause... I don't know...

```
mysql> select * from employee_expert;

+------+---------+
| eNum | package |
+------+---------+
| E246 | Excel   |
| E246 | MySQL   |
| E246 | Python  |
| E246 | Word    |
| E403 | Jave    |
| E403 | MySQL   |
| E892 | Excel   |
| E892 | PHP     |
| E892 | Python  |
+------+---------+




       mysql> SELECT eNum, package 
       FROM employee_expert 
       WHERE (package = 'MySQL' OR package = 'Python') AND (package = 'MySQL' OR    package = 'Python') 
       GROUP BY package;



+------+---------+
| eNum | package |
+------+---------+
| E246 | MySQL   |
| E246 | Python  |
+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` clauses contains unnecessary duplication of the condition `package = 'MySQL' OR package = 'Python'`. Using `WHERE (package = 'MySQL' OR package = 'Python')` is enough. Or, to make it more readable you can write `WHERE package IN ('MySQL', 'Python')`.

Your query selects the employees that know 'MySQL' **or** 'Python' **or both**.

It looks like you want to select the employees that know **both** 'MySQL' **and** 'Python'. You need to use a `JOIN` for this purpose:

```
SELECT f.eNum
FROM employee_expert f                        # 'f' from 'first'
  INNER JOIN employee_expert s USING(eNum)    # 's' from 'second'
WHERE f.package = 'MySQL'
  AND s.package = 'Python'
```

Unfortunately, this approach does not scale very well if you need to find by a larger set of languages. A better approach would be to use the original query and group the results by `eNum` like this:

```
SELECT eNum, COUNT(DISTINCT package) AS nbLangs
FROM employee_expert
WHERE package IN ('MySQL', 'Python')   # <------------------------------------+
GROUP BY eNum           # Make one entry for each employee                    |
HAVING nbLangs = 2      # Replace '2' with the number of items in this list --+
```

This query counts the number of known languages for all the employees that know **at least** one of the languages in the list then keeps only those that knows **all of them**.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the design itself, come to think of it, an employee can master MANY packages and a package can be mastered by MANY employees, it's a many to many relationship, in terms of database that will produce a table `employee_package` for example which contains a primary key composed of the primary key of each table

```
+------+------------+
| eNum | package_id |
+------+------------+
| E246 | 1          |
| E246 | 2          |
| E246 | 3          |
| E892 | 1          |
+------+------------+
```

then your request will be something like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.eNum from employees e JOIN employee_package ep on ep.eNum = e.eNum 
WHERE ep.package_id = 1 OR ep.package_id = 2
-- let's say that id 1 is for MySQL and id 2 is for Python
```

Comment: This query selects the employees that knows at least one of the languages from the list. The OP wants to select the employees that knows both languages (or, at least, this is how I understand the question).